# Lagged values not showing in the facet wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I would like the lagged values of 2014 (2013) to show in the 2014 facet wrap, including its respective colour from the 2013 facet.

This is my code:

```
ggplot() +
geom_sf(data=st_centroid(table1) ,aes(color=as.factor(year)),size=0.5) +
theme_void() +
facet_wrap(~year,ncol=4)
```

[image: Facet Wrap]

I have tried creating a second dataset and plotting it against the previous one but it did not work:

```
table1 <- ERF %>% select(year,geometry) %>% 
  filter(year>=2013,year<=2014)
table2 <- ERF %>% select(year,geometry) %>% 
  filter(year>=2013,year<=2014) %>% 
  mutate(year=year-1)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data=st_centroid(table1) ,aes(color=as.factor(year)),size=0.5) +
  geom_sf(data=st_centroid(table2), aes(color=as.factor(year)) ,size=0.5) +
  theme_void() +
  facet_wrap(~year,ncol=4)
```

here is the data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W4z3wPuDzW8dInWx6_xPrEfyhk12XXBc/view?usp=share_link

Answer (score 0):

You could bind your data to a version with the facet shifted one year. Here, I distinguish between `year` (the data's original year) and `facet_year` (the facet I want to see it in).

```
df <- data.frame(year = c(2013, 2014),
                 val = c(6,7))
```

First, something like your example:

```
ggplot(df, aes("", val, color = factor(year))) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~year)
```

[image]

Now, binding the data to a version of itself shifted forward. Now, the 2014 facet shows data from 2013 too.

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df |> mutate(facet_year = year),
          df |> mutate(facet_year = year + 1)) |>

ggplot(aes("", val, color = factor(year))) +
geom_point() +
facet_wrap(~facet_year)
```

[image]